# Getting missing parameter "accessToken" exception using fastify-oauth-server (npmjs)

Tags: oauth-2.0, fastify

I set up a fastify server that uses fastify-outh-server with the in-memory-model.  I'm trying to connect from postman using a "client_credentials" flow.   The server throws an exception "missing parameter: accessToken" when I try to retrieve a token.   The in-memory-model looks to be getting the right client and saving the token.  The exception occurs after that in the oauth2-server code which I don't believe I should have to touch.   I see that the code creating a new TokenModel is getting null data.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you add some code instead of an image? how do you register the plugin? how did you write the test?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did figure out the problem and have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I enlarged my search and eventually ended up at the oauth2-server module.   This is the module that the fastify-oauth-server is wrapping.  After some reading I found that others had had problems with the inMemoryModel.js (example).  That is what I had been using for testing. I found a git repo where this had been corrected ([Code to fix the problem](https://gist.github.com/kobi/7c0b8196d8b585dcc62d71947f909342))  The example saveToken method was not returning the token.   That solved my problem.